# Show variable herited from interface on Unity inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I want to create some game in Unity and I've started by creating a class hierarchy in order to be able to use polymorphism. So I've created some interfaces with both methods and also variables.

As said in the [C# interfaces documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx), I've created my interface with variables like this

```
public interface IUnit : ISelectable {
  int   healthPoint { get; set; }
  bool  isIndestructible { get; set; }
  /******************************/
  void  takeDamage(int dmg);
  void  die();
}
```

Now, I'm implementing my interface in a class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class BasicUnit : MonoBehaviour, IUnit {

  private int       _healthPoint;
  public int        HealthPoint         { get { return (_healthPoint); } set { _healthPoint = value; } }
  private bool      _isIndestructible;
  public bool       isIndestructible    { get { return (_isIndestructible); } set { _isIndestructible = value; } }

  public void   takeDamage (int dmg)
  {
      if (this.isIndestructible == false) {
          this.HealthPoint -= dmg;
          if (this.HealthPoint <= 0) {
              die();
          }
      }
  }

  public void die()
  {
      Destroy(gameObject);
  }
}
```

My problem is that my variables, `healthPoint` and `isIndestructible` are not shown in Unity's inspector despite being public variables. I've tried using `[System.Serializable]` but it doesn't work.

Well my question is quite simple, **how should I do to show my inherited variables in Unity's inspector ?**

Note: I'm trying to have nice and readable code, so if possible I would like to keep my IUnit class as an interface and my variables inside my IUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your inherited code that's hidden. Inheritance has no effect whatsoever in the display of the fields.
Rather, what's really happening is that you have two fields that are serializeable, but marked private (_healthPoint &  _isIndestructible),
and two public Properties. Unfortunately, Unity can't process and display properties out of the box.

Fortunately, here's a simple solution. I found this on Unity Wiki, and saved it for a situation like this :)

[Expose Proerties in Inspector from Unity Wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ExposePropertiesInInspector_Generic)

***How it works***
Basically, any Monobehavior that you want the properties exposed on should inherit from ***ExposableMonoBehaviour*** and also
1. private fields (like your _healthPoint) should have the [SerializeField, HideInInspector] attributes
2. public properties (like HealthPoint) should have the [ExposeProperty] attribute

Partial example

```
public class BasicUnit : ExposableMonoBehaviour, IUnit {

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private int _healthPoint;
    [ExposeProperty]
    public int HealthPoint { 
        get { return (_healthPoint); } 
        set { _healthPoint = value; } 
    }


}
```

Comment: As @Venkat mentioned, [ExposeProperty] seems to be the correct answer for your problem.

Comment: Great answer, sorry I couldn't try it earler =)

Answer (score 3):

If still anyone have problem with setting value of the variables inherited from an interface in inspector, Thanks to Jetbrains Rider , I found a solution. just use [field: SerializeField] before introducing the variable in the child script.

example :

```
public interface IAlive
{
    float HealthPoint { get; set;}
}
public class Cat : MonoBehaviour , IAlive
{
    [field: SerializeField] float HealthPoint { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, you can use `[SerializeField]` on any field you want to show in the inspector. However, it have to be used on the private variable you want to serialize, not the public one.

```
public class BasicUnit : MonoBehaviour, IUnit {

  [SerializeField]
  private int       _healthPoint;
  public int        HealthPoint         { get { return (_healthPoint); } set { _healthPoint = value; } }
  [SerializeField]
  private bool  _isIndestructible;
  public bool       isIndestructible    { get { return (_isIndestructible); } set { _isIndestructible = value; } }
}
```

Comment: While your answer does technically solve the issue, it defeats the purpose of making a variable private.